# Decomposing evaluation in case class

Tags: scala

I got this code from [here](https://gist.github.com/sschaef/5529436): It's a very simple expression evaluation

```
  sealed abstract class Tree
  case class Add(t1: Tree, t2: Tree) extends Tree
  case class Sub(t1: Tree, t2: Tree) extends Tree
  case class Mul(t1: Tree, t2: Tree) extends Tree
  case class Div(t1: Tree, t2: Tree) extends Tree
  case class Num(t: Double) extends Tree

  def eval(t: Tree): Double = t match {
    case Add(t1, t2) => eval(t1)+eval(t2)
    case Sub(t1, t2) => eval(t1)-eval(t2)
    case Mul(t1, t2) => eval(t1)*eval(t2)
    case Div(t1, t2) => eval(t1)/eval(t2)
    case Num(t) => t
  }
```

How can I decompose eval function into case classes (e.g. Add) so I can have something like: (How Scala compiler do this for Function*, I think these should have same answers)

```
sealed abstract class Tree{
def eval:???
}
case class Add(t1: Tree, t2: Tree) extends Tree{
  def eval = ???
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the abstract `Tree` class have an `eval` method that returns a `Double`:

```
sealed abstract class Tree {
    def eval: Double
}
case class Add(t1: Tree, t2: Tree) extends Tree {
    def eval = t1.eval + t2.eval
}
case class Sub(t1: Tree, t2: Tree) extends Tree {
    def eval = t1.eval - t2.eval
}
case class Num(t: Double) extends Tree {
    def eval = t
}
```

And then:

```
val tree = Add(Num(1), Sub(Num(2), Num(1))) //1+(2-1)
tree.eval //2.0
```

Another approach is to define a case class for each branching size of the tree:

```
sealed abstract class Tree {
    def eval: Double
}
case class Tree2(func: (Double, Double) => Double)(d1: Tree, d2: Tree) extends Tree {
    def eval = func(d1.eval, d2.eval)
}
case class Tree1(func: Double => Double)(d1: Tree) extends Tree {
    def eval = func(d1.eval)
}
case class Tree0()(d1: Double) extends Tree {
    def eval = d1
}
```

Then you can define new tree operations as `vals` relatively ad-hoc, without defining new classes.  This is sometimes preferable:

```
val Add = Tree2(_ + _) _
val Sub = Tree2(_ - _) _
val Num = Tree0() _
```

Of course, nothing here is special to `Double`.  You could make `Tree` generic to parameterize the return type.  Here's a small generic version, and an implementation with `Strings`:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[T] {
    def eval: T
}
case class Add(t1: Tree[String], t2: Tree[String]) extends Tree[String] {
    def eval = t1.eval + t2.eval
}
case class Sub(t1: Tree[String], t2: Tree[String]) extends Tree[String] {
    def eval = t1.eval.replaceAll(t2.eval, "")
}
case class Str(t: String) extends Tree[String] {
    def eval = t
}

Add(Str("foo"), Sub(Str("barfoobarfoo"), Str("foo"))).eval //"foobarbar"
```

Comment: This works just for depth of one, if I want have `Sum(Sum(Sum(Num(2),Num(1)),Num(3)),Num(4))` then it would fail, am I right?

Comment: @Omid No, these solutions work for trees of arbitrary length.  Try running this in the REPL, and then evaluate `Sum(Sum(Sum(Num(2),Num(1)),Num(3)),Num(4)).eval` and you'll get `10.0`, as desired!

Comment: thanks! you are right, one more thing: Is it the same if I type the output instead of `Double`? Let say `def eval:T` where `T<:ValLike`

Comment: Sure!  You can make all these methods and classes generic and nothing should be very different.

Comment: I am thinking of some cases that the class that extends `ValLike` doesn't support `-*` and I don't know where is the best place to handle this issue!

Comment: @Omid The example I added to the answer uses `String`, which doesn't have `-`.  If there isn't a natural subtraction or multiplication on some of the values, they need not create those operation classes!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75669/discussion-between-ben-reich-and-omid).